# Android and Moshi Adapter with generic type

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I'm trying to use moshi with my Android project, but I am running into some problems.

Here is a stripped down sample JSON

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "label": "May",
      "schedule_items": [
        {
          "type": "event",
          "item": {
            "foo": "bar",
            "some_prop": 1
          },
          "schedule_item_groups": [
            {
              "label": "Friday May 4th",
              "schedule_items": [
                {
                  "type": "check_in",
                  "item": {
                    "a_different_prop": 15
                  },
                  "schedule_item_groups": null
                },
                {
                  "type": "game",
                  "item": {
                    "yet_another_different_prop": 3598
                  },
                  "schedule_item_groups": null
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it is a list of `ScheduleGroups`, and within that object you have a label and `schedule_items`.  Which is an array of `ScheduleItem` with *3* fields:

- `type`: String label to identify which type of Item this is
- `item`: Can be of class `Event`, `Game`, and `CheckIn`
- `schedule_item_groups`: A `ScheduleGroup` which is a list of more -
  `ScheduleItems`

So the first problem is a `ScheduleGroup` has a list of `ScheduleItems` and each item can have it's own list of `ScheduleGroup` containing more items.

The second problem is the `item` field, it needs to be instantiated as one of three classes: `Event`, `Game`, `CheckIn`.

I've been working at it for awhile, and so far I can only get one working at a time, but not both.

Here are the data classes (I have only included one of the `Item` classes):

```
data class ScheduleGroup(
    val label: String,
    val schedule_items: List<ScheduleItem<Any>>
)
data class ScheduleItem<out T>(
    val type: String,
    val schedule_item_groups: List<ScheduleGroup>
    val item: T
) {
    abstract class Item
}
data class Event(
    val some_prop: Int,
    val foo: String
) : ScheduleItem.Item()
```

This is how I got the dynamic Generic class `Item` to work:

```
@FromJson
fun fromJson(map: Map<*, *>): ScheduleItem<Any> {
    val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val type: String = map["type"] as String
    val itemJson = moshi.adapter(Map::class.java).toJson(map["item"] as Map<*, *>)

    val item = when (type) {
        EventType.EVENT -> moshi.adapter(Event::class.java).fromJson(itemJson)
        EventType.GAME -> moshi.adapter(Game::class.java).fromJson(itemJson)
        EventType.CHECK_IN, EventType.CHECK_OUT ->
            moshi.adapter(CheckIn::class.java).fromJson(itemJson)
        else -> throw Error("Unknown type was found $type")
    }

val scheduleGroupType = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, ScheduleGroup::class.java)
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    val scheduleGroupJson = moshi.adapter<List<ScheduleGroup>>(scheduleGroupType)
        .toJson(map["schedule_item_groups"] as List<ScheduleGroup>?)

    val list: List<ScheduleGroup>? = moshi
        .adapter<List<ScheduleGroup>>(scheduleGroupType).fromJson(scheduleGroupJson)

    return ScheduleItem(type, list ?: listOf(), item)
}
```

It will correctly create the right `Item` class, but when I try to add the `List<ScheduleGroup>` I get errors, and no matter what I do I cannot seem to get both to work.

Edit:

I Have updated the code to show what I'm using to try and deserialize the `schedule_item_groups` which is a `List<ScheduleGroup>`.

I get an error: (This is a different error than I got before...)

> com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final java.lang.String field com.roomroster.mobile_android.data.api.schedule.models.ScheduleGroup.label to com.squareup.moshi.LinkedHashTreeMap at $.data[0].schedule_items[1]

Comment: Can you please post the errors you get?

Comment: I have added the code I'm using, and the error.

Comment: You might be able to adapter something from https://github.com/square/moshi/pull/264/files

Comment: We'll get better documentation on this use case in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out awhile ago, but I guess I can post what I did in case it will help anyone in the future.

First I created a temporary intermediatry class, to hold the data before the generic data was made.

```
data class ScheduleItem<T>(
    val date: Date,
    val type: String,
    var scheduleGroups: List<ScheduleGroup> = listOf(),
    var item: T
) {
    data class ScheduleItemJson(
        val date: Date,
        val type: String,
        val schedule_item_groups: List<ScheduleGroup>? = listOf(),
        val item: Any
    )
}
```

Then in the adapter

```
@FromJson fun fromJson(item: ScheduleItem.ScheduleItemJson): ScheduleItem<Any> {
    val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val json = moshi.adapter(Map::class.java).toJson(item.item as Map<*, *>)

    return ScheduleItem(
        item.date,
        item.type,
        item.schedule_item_groups ?: listOf(),
        when (item.type) {
            ItemType.GAME -> moshi.adapter(GameItem::class.java).fromJson(json)
            ItemType.EVENT -> moshi.adapter(EventItem::class.java).fromJson(json)
            ItemType.CHECK_IN, ItemType.CHECK_OUT ->
                moshi.adapter(ReservationItem::class.java)
                     .fromJson(json).apply { this!!.type = item.type }
            else -> ScheduleItem.NullItem()
        }!!
    )
}
```

The `when` statement is what creates the `<T : Item>` and passes it to the `ScheduleItem` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I went through similar problem, I made use of sealed class and JsonAdapter to build models dynamically. 
I posted my answer in another post, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56897476/5584709